# Pascal. Recursive function to count amount of odd numbers in the sequence

Tags: recursion, freepascal

I need to write recursive function to count amount of odd numbers in the sequence

Here my initial code:

```
program OddNumbers;

{$APPTYPE CONSOLE}

uses
  SysUtils;

function GetOddNumbersAmount(const x: array of integer; count,i:integer):integer;
begin
   if((x[i] <> 0) and (x[i] mod 2=0)) then
   begin
     count:= count + 1;
     GetOddNumbersAmount:=count;
   end;

   i:=i+1;
   GetOddNumbersAmount:=GetOddNumbersAmount(x, count, i);
end;


var X: array[1..10] of integer;
    i,amount: integer;

begin
  writeln('Enter your sequence:');

  for i:=1 to 10 do
    read(X[i]);

  amount:= GetOddNumbersAmount(X, 0, 1);
  writeln('Amount of odd numbers: ', amount);

  readln;
  readln;
end.
```

When i type the sequence and press "enter", program closed without any errors and i can't see the result.

Also, i think my function isn't correct.
Can someone help with that code?

**UPD:**

```
function GetOddNumbersAmount(const x: array of integer; count,i:integer):integer;
begin
   if((x[i] <> 0) and (x[i] mod 2<>0)) then
     count:= count + 1;

   if(i = 10) then
     GetOddNumbersAmount:=count
   else
     GetOddNumbersAmount:=GetOddNumbersAmount(x, count, i+1);
end;
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You don't provide an end of recursion, i.e., you always call your function `GetOddNumbersAmount` again, and your program never terminates. Thus, you get an array index error (or a stack overflow) and your program crashes.

Please note, that every recursion need a case where it terminates, i.e. does *not* call itself. In your case, it should return if there are no elements in the array left.

In addition, you are counting the even numbers, not the odd ones.

Comment: This is also a horrible demonstration of recursion. Sigh.

Answer (score 0):

You passed a static array to a dynamic so the index get confused:
Allocat the array with
      SetLength(X,10)
  allocates an array of 10 integers, indexed 0 to 9.

Dynamic arrays are always integer-indexed, always starting from 0!

```
  SetLength(X,10)
  for it:=0 to 9 do begin
    X[it]:= random(100);
```

And second if you know the length a loop has more advantages:

```
function GetEvenNumbersAmount(const x: array of integer; count,i:integer):integer;
begin
  for i:= 0 to length(X)-1 do 
    if((x[i] <> 0) and (x[i] mod 2=0)) then begin
    inc(count);
   //write(inttostr(X[i-1])+ ' ')  :debug
   end;
 result:=count;
```

end;